# Remote - ssh -Experiencing SSH connection error to a previously accessible remote Linux server; [visual-studio-code]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I started using connect to remote option in VScode .
After soemtime i am getting errror while connecting to same linux server.And none changes are happend in destination linux server.
But not understanding why suddenly its not connecting to destination server

However, I have tried to connect using git bash and it is successful.

tried solutions:

1. The first solution i tried the extension command: Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host
2. delete the .vscode-server folder on destination directory
3. Remove the known host entry for that specific server
4. Tried with Uninstall VScode completely (include all the directory present )

can someone help me with this issue ?
earlier its working thats why more concerns about it.

Error log

```
[11:13:45.651] Log Level: 2
[11:13:45.669] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+test_main_host", attempt 1
[11:13:45.671] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[11:13:45.671] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[11:13:45.672] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:13:45.672] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"192.168.36.130":"linux","10.5.0.10":"linux"}
[11:13:45.673] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[11:13:45.673] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[11:13:45.673] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[11:13:45.673] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[11:13:45.674] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[11:13:45.674] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[11:13:45.674] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[11:13:45.674] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[11:13:45.675] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[11:13:45.675] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[11:13:45.675] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[11:13:45.678] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[11:13:45.678] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[11:13:45.683] VS Code version: 1.86.0
[11:13:45.683] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.108.0
[11:13:45.683] win32 x64
[11:13:45.687] SSH Resolver called for host: test_main_host
[11:13:45.687] Setting up SSH remote "test_main_host"
[11:13:45.696] Using commit id "05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937" and quality "stable" for server
[11:13:45.704] Install and start server if needed
[11:18:04.315] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.316] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:18:04.317] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.321] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:18:04.322] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.324] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:18:04.324] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.327] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:18:04.328] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.332] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[11:18:04.333] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[11:18:04.413] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[11:18:04.422] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 64049 "test_main_host" bash
[11:18:04.429] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:18:04.703] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:18:04.704] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:18:05.582] > 6b01c55d7f06: running
[11:18:05.621] > Missing GLIBCXX >= 3.4.25!
> Found versions 3.4.1
> 3.4.2
> 3.4.3
> 3.4.4
> 3.4.5
> 3.4.6
> 3.4.7
> 3.4.8
> 3.4.9
> 3.4.10
> 3.4.11
> 3.4.12
> 3.4.13
> 3.4.14
> 3.4.15
> 3.4.16
> 3.4.17
> 3.4.18
> 3.4.19
> Missing GLIBC >= 2.28!
> Found version ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
> 6b01c55d7f06$$1$$
> Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd
> 937/vscode-remote-lock.root.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937
> Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd
> 70ea3bdf775fd937...
> Checking /root/.vscode-server/.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937.log and 
> /root/.vscode-server/.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937.pid for a running
>  server
> Looking for server with pid: 25160
> Starting VS Code Server... "/root/.vscode-server/bin/05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70e
> a3bdf775fd937/bin/code-server" --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-l
> icense-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level all   &> "
> /root/.vscode-server/.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937.log" < /dev/null 
> The VS Code Server log file is /root/.vscode-server/.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70e
> a3bdf775fd937.log
[11:18:05.661] > 
> printenv:
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=1864838
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.4.1.11 64071 22
>     PERL5LIB=/root/perl5/lib/perl5:
>     PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base /root/perl5
>     USER=root
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server
>     PATH=/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us
> r/sbin:/usr/bin
>     MAIL=/var/mail/root
>     MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/maven
>     PWD=/root
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     HOME=/root
>     SHLVL=2
>     PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=:/root/perl5
>     LOGNAME=root
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.4.1.11 64071 10.5.0.10 22
>     CLASSPATH=.
>     LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
>     PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
> Removing old logfile at /root/.vscode-server/.05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf77
> 5fd937.log
[11:18:05.672] > 
> Spawned remote server: 29520
> Waiting for server log...
[11:18:05.688] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:05.767] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:05.861] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:05.952] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
[11:18:06.046] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:06.106] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:19.819] > 
[11:18:19.837] > Waiting for server log...
[11:18:19.897] > Waiting for server log...
>  
> *
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacyst
> atement).
> *
[11:18:19.916] > 
> 
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /root/.vscode-server/.0504
> 7486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937.log >>>
[11:18:19.929] > Warning: Missing GLIBCXX >= 3.4.25! from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
> Warning: Missing GLIBC >= 2.28! from /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
> Error: Missing required dependencies. Please refer to our FAQ https://aka.ms/vsc
> ode-remote/faq/old-linux for additional information.
> <<< End of server log
> 6b01c55d7f06: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==centos==
> arch==x86_64==
> vscodeArch==x64==
> bitness==64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/0==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==14266==
> 6b01c55d7f06: end
[11:18:19.932] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==centos==
arch==x86_64==
vscodeArch==x64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/run/user/0==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==14266==

[11:18:19.938] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at g.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:460179)
    at d (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:453522)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:455792)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:581100)
    at async c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:540958
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:544264)
    at async k (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:537923)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:541635)
    at async c:\Users\test\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:807794
[11:18:19.949] ------
[11:18:19.971] > 
[11:18:21.243] "install" terminal command done
[11:18:21.244] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Answer (score 1):

if this happened after you update vscode to 1.86.0, then download vscode history version 1.85.2 and install it, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Update the vscode version to 1.86.1 and it is connecting now.